# In election website nothing loading after Loading user profile on main site

Tags: bug, status-completed, election-page

I just visited [election website](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow) and in Please wait, Reticulating Splines list it got stuck to the Loading user profile on main site in console it shows error `TypeError: candidates is undefined`

> [image]

Comment: I gave up on that page a long time ago - its great in theory but in practice it just doesn't work.

Comment: Tim Stone and Yi Jiang are already aware of the issue; we're still waiting for a fix from them.

Comment: [I went to report this in the *allegedly* Election chatroom yesterday](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7922718#7922718). Since it wasn't clear at all where to report problems like this though

Comment: [Yi Jiang has a fix and is waiting for it to be rolled out](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7933659#7933659)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry about this. I just [pushed out a quick fix](https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-election-stats/source/detail?r=27c32f4803f135dc9426d99a88c5c4d27c1efe8d) for this. We're still waiting for SE to push out the change to the actual page.

The problem is that the election statistics page relies, basically, on page scraping for details about nominees. Which means that whenever the page's markup changes, something will break, which is what happened here. We've been asking for an [API endpoint for election data](https://stackapps.com/questions/1962/could-we-please-have-election-data-added-to-the-api) for a while now. Please support the feature request so that we don't see this happening in the future again.